# How to access the value of a math.random calculation?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a program that simulates a card shuffler. The program should randomly selects a random image within an array and displays it to the screen. Then it deletes that image from the array before running again. The problem I'm having is storing the value of the randomized number so I can delete said array position from the array. I'm pretty sure the math.random calculation needs to be within a function, but I'm having a hard time using that value to randomize the array position while simultaneously storing that random value.

```
var shuffler = {
 cards: [...]
displayCard: function() {
   document.getElementById("card-1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
shuffler.cards[shuffler.randomizer()] + ')';
},
  randomizer: function() {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length) = randomized;
    return this.randomized;
    shuffler.cards.splice(randomized, 1)
  }
}
shuffler.displayCard();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store the value correctly because following line is errorsome

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length) = randomized;
```

`=` sign in programming is not like `=` in math. It just assigns the value of right side to left side. Thus, you should do it like this instead:

```
this.randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length);
```

Comment: Knew it had to be something dumb that I was forgetting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet you have you're returning before you splice from your array, making it dead code that's unreachable.

In terms of answering the title of this question, you're in the right spirits of just simply storying the random number as a variable, however you need to have proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**bro check your syntax**

```
randomizer: function() {
    Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length) = randomized;
    return this.randomized;
    shuffler.cards.splice(randomized, 1)
}
```

**I think it will be**

```
randomizer: function() {
    this.randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length);
    this.displayCard(this.randomized);
    shuffler.cards.splice(this.randomized, 1);
    return this.randomized;
}
```

and you also need to declare `randomized` property in your shuffler object.

You also need to fix your `displayCard` method.

```
displayCard: function(index) {
   document.getElementById("card-1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
shuffler.cards[index] + ')';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. First one is with assignment of randomized. See the line

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length) = randomized;
```

Here the LeftHandSide of assignment expression is an expression which is wrong. It should be

```
let randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length);
```

The second problem is that you are using `splice()` after `return` move it before `return`

The last problem is that you are using the variable name inside the methods of the object. You should use `this` instead of `shuffler`. The final code will look like.

```
var shuffler = {
 cards: [...]
 displayCard: function() {
   document.getElementById("card-1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
   this.cards[this.randomizer()] + ')';
 },
 randomizer: function() {
    let randomized =  Math.floor(Math.random() * shuffler.cards.length);
    this.cards.splice(randomized, 1)
    return randomized;
 }
}
shuffler.displayCard();
```